# PostgreSQL - Declaring a variable that can store multiple values

Tags: postgresql

I need a way to declare a variable that can store multiple values. My first attempt was to declare a variable using the TABLE type:

```
DECLARE __id TABLE(results_id integer);
```

However this didnt go as planned, giving me type-declaration errors. My next attempt was to make an integer[] type

```
DECLARE __id integer[];
```

but it ended up giving me an error of that values needs to be inserted using curly braces whenever i attempted to insert them with a select function.

```
SELECT p.id FROM files.main p
WHERE p.reference = __reference
AND p.platform = __platform_id
INTO __id;
```

I wonder if there is any way to solve this problem?

Comment: "A variable that can store multiple values" is usually a table with multiple columns. In Postgres you can also use [JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) or [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), but a table is the first thing you should try. A subquery might also be the answer. Can you tell us more about what you plan to store and why?

Comment: @Schwern i need an array, where i store all the result, each result will be run in a function and the results will be inserted into a different table object

Comment: @Crated, what did you end up doing? Were you able to get past the "curly braces" error while using a variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table name `t` you can declare a variable of the type `t`

```
create or replace function tf1() returns int as 
$BODY$
DECLARE
 var  public.t;
BEGIN
    select * from public.t into var limit 1;

  return var.id;
END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;

select * from tf1();
```

Comment: This only knows for existing tables, this wont work for non-existing ones

Answer (score 0):

> i need an array to use them afterwards, where every result will be run in a function and the results will be inserted into a table object of same type [– Crated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159336/postgresql-declaring-a-variable-that-can-store-multiple-values?noredirect=1#comment109936585_62159336)

While you *can* do this with arrays and variables, it's simpler and faster to do it in a single query using an [`insert into select`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_insert_into_select.asp).

```
INSERT INTO some_other_table (some_column)
SELECT your_function(p.id)
FROM files.main p
WHERE p.reference = __reference
  AND p.platform = __platform_id
```

This will run each matching `p.id` through `your_function` and insert the results as `some_column` in `some_other_table`.

Comment: while this would solve the issue if the other table did exist, the issue is that the table does not exist. The table do however exist in the return type of the function, which i do get using the function files.get_file(id) where id is a standalone integer from __id.

Comment: @Crated It's hard to say without full details, please put them into your question, but you can use a subquery to select from the `files.get_file` table into another. Let's say it returns `table ( name text, size int )`. `insert into other_table(name, size) select name, size from ( select files.get_file(p.id) from files.main p where ... ) as files(name, size)`.